# If $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F_p[x]$, prove that $f(x) | x^{p^k}-x$ iff $\deg(f) | k$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Here is a lemma I encountered here: https://imathworks.com/math/math-why-xpn-x1-is-irreducible-in-mathbbf_p-only-when-n1-or-np2/

Lemma: If $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F_p[x]$, Then for any positive integer k:
$$f(x)\mid x^{p^k}-x \Leftrightarrow \deg(f) \mid k $$

I think I can show "$\Rightarrow $" part as follows:

Suppose $f(x)\mid x^{p^k}-x$. Let $L$ be the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x$ over $F_p$, $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$, Then:
$$F\subset F(\alpha)\subset L $$
By tower theorem:
$$k=[L:F]=[L:F(\alpha)]\cdot [F(\alpha):F]=\deg(f)\cdot m $$

But I cannot show the other side. Is there any hints? Thanks.

Comment: The quotient ring $E = F_p[x]/(f(x))$ is a field of size $p^d$, where $d = \deg f$.  In $E$, show$x^{p^d} = x$. Then take $p^d$-th powers of both sides repeatedly.

Comment: @KCd Thank you very much! I have proven the other side following your hint!

Comment: This could be a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/219213/11619). There could even be an older one, but I did not find one back in the day. I won't cast the first vote to close, because A) I happened to answer that one, and B) my vote would take immediate effect by the dupehammer rules.